# Select row y traer los valores

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta tabla

```js
function highlight(e) {
    if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
    e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
    
}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect(){
var $row=$(this).parent().find('td');
    var clickeedID=$row.eq(0).text();
   // alert(clickeedID);
}

$("#tst").click(function(){
    var value =$(".selected td:first").html();
    value = value || "No row Selected";
    alert(value);
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: brown;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>    
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
         <td><select name="sel" id="sel" >
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><select name="" id="hola">
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><select name="" id="hola">
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="fnselect()" />
```

Cuando le doy click al boton `OK`  me trae solo el primer valor de la tabla seleccionada. estoy tratando de hacer que me traiga todos los valores incluyendo el valor del select.

Por ejemplo para que no me traiga todos los datos del select los cuales son `123` y `456` me muestre solo el seleccionado. y no los 2 valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el selector de Jquery estas estipulando que coja el primer `td` solo ...

```
var value =$(".selected td:first").html();
```

Asi que deberias quitar eso y cambiar el `html` por un `text`

```
var value =$(".selected").text();
```

Pero para que te coja el seleccionado del dropmenu no puedes coger la linea entera y ya. Has de ir iterando todos los `td` con la funcion `each()` y concatenando su `text()` hasta que encuentres un `td` que tiene un `select`

Entonces cojes el `option` que está seleccionado y de ahi su `text`.

```
$(".selected").find("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).has("select").length) { //el td contiene un select

        value += ($(this).find("option:selected").text());

    }else {
        value += $(this).text() + "\n";
    }
});
```

```js
function highlight(e) {
  if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
  e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';

}

var table = document.getElementById('table'),
  selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;

function fnselect() {
  var $row = $(this).parent().find('td');
  var clickeedID = $row.eq(0).text();
  // alert(clickeedID);
}

$("#tst").click(function() {
  var value = "";
  $(".selected").find("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).has("select").length) {

      value += ($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    } else {
      value += $(this).text() + "\n";
      //alert($(this).text());
    }
  });
  value = value || "No row Selected";
  alert(value);
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background-color: brown;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>    
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
         <td><select name="sel" id="sel" >
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><select name="" id="hola">
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><select name="" id="hola">
             <option value="1">Seleccion</option>
             <option value="2">123</option>
             <option value="3">456</option>
         </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="tst" value="OK" onclick="fnselect()" />
```

Comment: Por ejemplo para que no me traiga todos los datos del select los cuales son  `123` y `456` me muestre solo el seleccionado. y no los 2 valores.

Comment: Intenta dar clic exactamente despues del border donde termina el `select` y veras como se cambia todo el contenido a rojo.